# Best Linux distro for LAMP web development?

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtualbox, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Linux flavor for web application development (LAMP)](https://serverfault.com/questions/140176/best-linux-flavor-for-web-application-development-lamp)

I know this question has been asked before.

My qualifier is that I want something with Apache/PHP/MySQL already installed, configured and ready to use. Maybe with some kind of control panel with things like PHPMyAdmin.

I also want something that will run in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend CentOS for this or RedHat if you want management/support at a cost $.

Answer (score 0):

Any Linux distro will fullfill your needs, and of course there'll be plenty of opinions about what to use.

If you're targeting for easy administration I would try starting with Ubuntu (http://www.ubuntu.com) and once you get more comfortable with Linux administration you can then choose amongst all the good options out there like Debian, CentOS, SuSe, etc